# How do I verify pushed commits?

Tags: github

Github gives the possibility to verify commits by [signing them with GPG](https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-using-gpg/).

After you do this, you get all your commits verified/signed. But, I have pushed commits before doing this. Is there a way to verify/sign those commits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would involve rewriting the history of your repository, either with:

- `git rebase -i`, with an edit and `git commit -S --amend --no-edit` on each commit
- or a [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

Something like [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1314044/141), but using any criteria you want:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'if [ <some criteria> ];
  then git commit-tree -S "$@";
  else git commit-tree "$@";
  fi' HEAD
```